# OPenCv- Mapping Images

Tags: java, opencv, image-processing

I am trying to crop an face out of an image and I do that by first detecting the face then mapping the area to another image but something is wrong.

Here is my code if you could help:

```
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.awt.image.WritableRaster;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;

import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;

import org.opencv.core.Core;
import org.opencv.core.Mat;
import org.opencv.core.MatOfRect;
 import org.opencv.core.Point;
 import org.opencv.core.Rect;
import org.opencv.core.Scalar;
import org.opencv.highgui.Highgui;
import org.opencv.objdetect.CascadeClassifier;

 public class FaceDetector {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    BufferedImage img = getImage("C:\\Users\\Yousra\\Desktop\\test4.jpg");

    System.loadLibrary(Core.NATIVE_LIBRARY_NAME);
    System.out.println("\nRunning FaceDetector");

    CascadeClassifier faceDetector = new CascadeClassifier("D:\\CS\\opencv\\sources\\data\\haarcascades\\haarcascade_frontalface_alt.xml");
    CascadeClassifier eyeDetector = new CascadeClassifier("D:\\CS\\opencv\\sources\\data\\haarcascades\\haarcascade_eye.xml");
    Mat image = Highgui
            .imread("C:\\Users\\Yousra\\Desktop\\test4.jpg");

    MatOfRect faceDetections = new MatOfRect();
    faceDetector.detectMultiScale(image, faceDetections);

    if( faceDetections.toArray().length == 0){
        //  load("C:\\Users\\Yousra\\Desktop\\download.jpg") ){
      System.out.println("not found");

    }

    System.out.println(String.format("Detected %s faces", faceDetections.toArray().length));


    for (Rect rect : faceDetections.toArray()) {
        Core.rectangle(image, new Point(rect.x, rect.y), new Point(rect.x + rect.width, rect.y + rect.height),
                new Scalar(0, 255, 0));


    }
    WritableRaster cr = img.getRaster();
    WritableRaster wr = img.copyData(null);

    for(int b=0; b<94; b++){
          for(int a=0; a<94; a++){
              for(int h = faceDetections.toArray()[0].y; h< 60+ 94; h++){
                  for(int w = faceDetections.toArray()[0].x; w< 50+ 94; w++){

                      wr.setSample(b, a, 0, cr.getSample(w, h, 0));


                  }

              }
          }

    }

    BufferedImage img2= new BufferedImage(94, 94, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);
    img2.setData(wr);

    JFrame frame = new JFrame("uiuxcu");
    frame.getContentPane().add(new JLabel(new ImageIcon(img2)));
    frame.pack();
    frame.setVisible(true);




    String filename = "ouput.png";
    System.out.println(String.format("Writing %s", filename));
    Highgui.imwrite(filename, image);
}
public static BufferedImage getImage(String imageName) {
    try {
        File input = new File(imageName);
        BufferedImage image = ImageIO.read(input);
        return image;
    } catch (IOException ie) {
        System.out.println("Error:" + ie.getMessage());
    }
    return null;
}}
```

The cropped image is not accurate at all and it doesn't show the face

Answer (score 1, accepted):

why not simply use submat http://docs.opencv.org/java/org/opencv/core/Mat.html#submat(org.opencv.core.Rect)

```
Mat face_cropped = image.submat( faceDetections.toArray()[0] );
```